# How to extract JSON from script with Python?

Tags: python, json, regex

I am parsing a scraped html page that contains a script with JSON inside. This JSON contains all info I am looking for but I can't figure out how to extract a valid JSON.

Minimal example:

```
my_string = '
        (function(){
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ || [];
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__.push(
        
           { *placeholder representing valid JSON inside* }
        );
        })()
'
```

The json inside is valid according to jsonlinter.

The result should be loaded into a dictionary:

```
import json
import re
my_json = re.findall(r'.*(?={\").*', my_string)[0] // extract json
data = json.loads(my_json)
// print(data)
```

regex: https://regex101.com/r/r0OYZ0/1

This try results in:

```
>>> data = json.loads(my_json)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
```

How can the JSON be extracted and loaded from the string with Python 3.7.x?

Comment: You have to use the `json.loads` method (don't forget the `s`). But your string doesn't seem to be valid json.

Comment: That is true, please read the question again.

Comment: The JSON you have in your regex example is not a valid JSON: `{"publicRuntimeConfig":{"public }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to extract this regex, its a very simple case and might not answerto all possible json variations:

```
my_string = '''
        (function(){
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ || [];
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__.push(
        
            {"tst":{"f":3}}
        );
        })()
'''
result = re.findall(r"push\(([{\[].*\:.*[}\]])\)",string3)[0]
result
>>> '{ "tst":{"f":3}}'
```

to parse it to dictionary now:

```
import json 

dictionary = json.loads(result)
type(dictionary)
>>>dict
```

Comment: Yes, the Json contains escaped characters unfortunatelly, do you know how to strip the escape sign?

Comment: the json contains: : ["string 5\'-mono. D

Comment: I updated the question and linked to regex101 with the full JSON

Comment: This is because the regex is not OK. The lookbehind captures the closing bracked. If you remove the ) at the end it will validat according to jsonlint.com

Comment: You are right! Looks I have another regex that works. .*(?:push\()(.*)\) Which one would you recommend using and why?

Comment: i am currently debugging it let me check it again

Comment: `json.loads(re.findall(r"push\(([{\[].*\:.*[}\]])\)",string3)[0])` is corrently working and is preffered, i also edited my code

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the below. Note that `{ *placeholder representing valid JSON inside* }` has to be a valid JSON.

```
my_string = '''
        <script>
            (function(){
              window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ || [];
              window.__PRELOADED_STATE__.push(
            
               {"foo":["bar1", "bar2"]}
            );
            })()
         </script>
'''

import re, json

my_json = re.findall(r'.*(?={\").*', my_string)[0].strip()
data = json.loads(my_json)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': ['bar1', 'bar2']}
```

Comment: Getting closer. I have now a similar regex: .*(?:push\()(.*)(?<=\)). You are right about the valid json. There is a escape char inside the JSON:  ["string 5\'-mono. Do you know a function that strips those?

Comment: Maybe you can just use `str.replace()`

Answer (score 0):

The `my_string` provided here is not valid JSON. For valid JSON, you can use `json.loads(JSON_STRING)`

```
import json

d = json.loads('{"test":2}')
print(d) # Prints the dictionary `{'test': 2}`
```

Comment: Well that is the whole point! Please read my question again, the "json inside is valid". I need to figure out how to remove the javascript code around it.

Comment: The question was edited to clarify that after I posted this answer.

Comment: Yes, after I saw your answer I tried to make things more clear. A regex might help, any ideas?